# How to sort the Activity Panel by Profile/User on an Account?

Tags: apex, filters

I am a relative novice with the Salesforce interface and platform itself so if I misuse some terminology, I apologize. In my current role,  I am undertaking the challenge of learning APEX and one of the tasks that I have been assigned is figuring out how to sort/filter the Activity Panel by Profile/User on an Account's page. I have been reading up on this topic but haven't found anything concrete. The closest thing to discovering an answer is the following link,
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XdlQAE

however based off of the conversation, I believe the post is referring to the desire to have an already built-in filter beyond **Date Range**, **Activities**, and **Activity Type**. So with that being said, I was wondering if it is possible to

1. Filter the Activity Panel by User and if so ...
2. How can I complete this task, whether through APEX or some other method

The following image is the Activity Panel that I am referring to, and the names highlighted in yellow are the User/Profiles that I am referring to. My objective is to sort the display by these  names instead of the default chronological order per month. Thank you in advance!

[image]

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003XdlQAE